# Are there ToS on "About Me"?

Tags: discussion

Without giving too much away, I'm planning a puzzle that will go on a bit of an adventure. However, one of the very first steps in the journey is visiting another SE of mine and reading the "About Me" section. That SE is not about riddles, but I have both a normal paragraph and an encrypted one in that "About Me".
Is there any ToS or rules that I would run into that would prohibit me from doing this? i.e. Is it okay for me to have a puzzle that goes outside of PuzzlingSE to another SE through the use of my "About Me" profile box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general policy on Puzzling.SE is that puzzles should be *self-contained* (i.e. they should not rely on information on a specific external site).

The main reason for this is that an external site could cease to exist at any point, leaving the puzzle insoluble.

In this case, however, the "external" site is another SE site, so it is probably safe to assume that it will continue to exist as long as Puzzling.SE does.

Precedent for relying on other SE sites:
[Cats, More Cats, and Questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23358)

Comment: I see! I will probably keep this puzzle idea live, then! I'll make sure to keep in mind that truly external sites should not be used.

Comment: @iiiidk Of course if you ever change or remove the encrypted element of the "About Me" in the other SE site, you will break the puzzle for future puzzlers.

Comment: Yep, I figured so. I don't plan to remove the encryptions, and I don't plan to use "About Me" in another puzzle. @GordonK